# Vector of Vector Initialization

Tags: c++, vector, initialization, deserialization

I am having a tough time getting my head wrapped around how to initialize a vector of vectors.

typedef vector< vector < vector < vector< float > > > > DataContainer;

I want this to conform to

```
level_1 (2 elements/vectors)
   level_2 (7 elements/vectors)
      level_3 (480 elements/vectors)
         level_4 (31 elements of float)
```

Addressing the elements isn't the issue.  That should be as simple as something like

```
dc[0][1][2][3];
```

The problem is that I need to fill it with data coming in out of order from a file such that successive items need to be placed something like

```
dc[0][3][230][22];
dc[1][3][110][6]; //...etc
```

So I need to initialize the V of V beforehand.

Am I psyching myself out or is this as simple as

```
for 0..1
    for 0..6
        for 0..479
           for 0..30
               dc[i][j][k][l] = 0.0;
```

It doesn't seem like that should work.  Somehow the top level vectors must be initialized first.

Any help appreciated.  I am sure this must be simpler than I am imagining.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

- Please **do not use nested vectors** if the *size of your storage is known ahead of time*, i.e. there is a *specific reason* why e.g. the first index must be of size 6, and will never change. Just use a plain array. Better yet, use `boost::array`. That way, you get all the benefits of having a plain array (save huge amounts of space when you go multi-dimensional), and the benefits of having a real object instantiation.
- Please **do not use nested vectors** if your storage must be *rectangular*, i.e. you might resize one or more of the dimensions, but every "row" must be the same length at some point. Use `boost::multi_array`. That way, you document "this storage is rectangular", save huge amounts of space and still get the ability to resize, benefits of having a real object, etc.

The thing about `std::vector` is that it (a) is meant to be resizable and (b) doesn't care about its contents in the slightest, as long as they're of the correct type. This means that if you have a `vector<vector<int> >`, then all of the "row vectors" must maintain their own separate book-keeping information about how long they are - even if you want to enforce that they're all the same length. It also means that they all manage separate memory allocations, which hurts performance (cache behaviour), and wastes even more space because of how `std::vector` reallocates. `boost::multi_array` is designed with the expectation that you may want to resize it, but won't be constantly resizing it by appending elements (rows, for a 2-dimensional array / faces, for a 3-dimensional array / etc.) to the end. `std::vector` is designed to (potentially) waste space to make sure that operation is not slow. `boost::multi_array` is designed to save space and keep everything neatly organized in memory.

**That said**:

Yes, you do need to do something before you can index into the vector. `std::vector` will not magically cause the indexes to pop into existence because you want to store something there. However, this is easy to deal with:

You can default-initialize the vector with the appropriate amount of zeros first, and then replace them, by using the `(size_t n, const T& value = T())` constructor. That is,

```
std::vector<int> foo(10); // makes a vector of 10 ints, each of which is 0
```

because a "default-constructed" int has the value 0.

In your case, we need to specify the size of each dimension, by creating sub-vectors that are of the appropriate size and letting the constructor copy them. This looks like:

```
typedef vector<float> d1;
typedef vector<d1> d2;
typedef vector<d2> d3;
typedef vector<d3> d4;
d4 result(2, d3(7, d2(480, d1(31))));
```

That is, an unnamed `d1` is constructed of size 31, which is used to initialize the default `d2`, which is used to initialize the default `d3`, which is used to initialize `result`.

There are other approaches, but they're much clumsier if you just want a bunch of zeroes to start. If you're going to read the entire data set from a file, though:

- You can use `.push_back()` to append to a vector. Make an empty `d1` just before the inner-most loop, in which you repeatedly `.push_back()` to fill it. Just after the loop, you `.push_back()` the result onto the `d2` which you created just before the next-innermost loop, and so on.
- You can resize a vector beforehand with `.resize()`, and then index into it normally (up to the amount that you resized to).

Comment: Neat construction there.  I'll give boost multi_array a shot.  Thanks for the in-depth answer.

Comment: In the new C++ standard, the functionality of `boost::array` is provided by `std::array` in the standard library.

Answer (score 2):

You would probably have to set a size or reserve memory

Could you do a for-each or a nested for that would call

```
myVector.resize(x); //or size
```

on each level.

Comment: .size() checks the current size of the vector. You want .resize().

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I admit this code is not elegant. I like @Karl answer which is the right way to go.

This code is compiled and tested. It printed 208320 zeroes which is expected (2 * 7 * 480 * 31)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

typedef vector< vector < vector < vector< float > > > > DataContainer;

int main()
{
    const int LEVEL1_SIZE = 2;
    const int LEVEL2_SIZE = 7;
    const int LEVEL3_SIZE = 480;
    const int LEVEL4_SIZE = 31;

    DataContainer dc;

    dc.resize(LEVEL1_SIZE);
    for (int i = 0; i < LEVEL1_SIZE; ++i) {
        dc[i].resize(LEVEL2_SIZE);
        for (int j = 0; j < LEVEL2_SIZE; ++j) {
            dc[i][j].resize(LEVEL3_SIZE);
            for (int k = 0; k < LEVEL3_SIZE; ++k) {
                dc[i][j][k].resize(LEVEL4_SIZE);
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < LEVEL1_SIZE; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < LEVEL2_SIZE; ++j) {
            for (int k = 0; k < LEVEL3_SIZE; ++k) {
                for (int l = 0; l < LEVEL4_SIZE; ++l) {
                    dc[i][j][k][l] = 0.0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < LEVEL1_SIZE; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < LEVEL2_SIZE; ++j) {
            for (int k = 0; k < LEVEL3_SIZE; ++k) {
                for (int l = 0; l < LEVEL4_SIZE; ++l) {
                    cout << dc[i][j][k][l] << " ";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I realized about 30 seconds after posting.  It should work but Karl's boost multi_array seems like a better choice.